# MongoDB uploading the wrong binary string from Python encoded value

Tags: python, mongodb, base64, pymongo

I was converting an .png file in Python using `base64.b64encode` and then uploading the Binary string to MongoDB.  However, after uploading, the value stored in mongodb is completely different than the one that gets printed out in python.

```py
encoded_img = base64.b64encode('logo.png')
print(encoded_img)
>> b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANwAAABKCAYAAADQZTrf...
```

When I go to MongoDB this is the value that shows up:

```
Image
:
Binary('aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlNVaEVVZ0FBQU53QUFBQktDQVlBQUFEUVpUcmZBQUFBQkdkQlRVRUFBTEdQQy94aEJRQUFBQ0JqU0ZK...')
```

Due to that, the image won't render if I try to publish it to a website using `<img src="data:image/png;base64, -insert encoded string here -`

Comment: Can you please show the code, where you are inserting the data in mongodb??

Comment: Looks like you do b64 encoding twice. Perhaps you are using some Mongo client that expects binary data and converts it for you. If you try to encode `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANwAAABKCAYAAADQZTrf...` you will receive the string `aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlNVaEVVZ0...`. So you need either to convert you `encoded_img` to string, or pass the binary file to mongo client

Comment: @Igor I think you're right. I was also thinking of using the built in Binary converter from bson and then uploading that to MongoDB and then do a b64 encode and b64 decode on the javascript webstack side